# Yii DropDown set values

Tags: php, yii

Dear stackoverflow users,

I have a problem creating a minimum and maximum value in Yii1 and cannot find the solution online. 
The problem is described as follows:
i need a dropdown (CHTML::dropdownlist) that has as minimumvalue 1 and as maximum value the var $avail

This is what i have tried, but obviously i am missing something:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('number', $avail, $avail);
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'number', $numbers);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what do you mean minimum and maximum values?

Comment: a select, starting from 0, to the $avail as the values for it. The keys need to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
$arr = array();
for($i=0;$i<=$avail;$i++)
$arr[$i] = $i;
echo CHtml::dropDownList('number', $avail, $arr);
```

Comment: glad to help don't forget to upvote my simple answer

Comment: upvoting requires a rep higher than 15 :$